# Minimal procedure to get a KDE desktop back after killing it by mistake

Tags: kde, window-manager

I wanted to kill an application with Al-Control-Escape+Enter but the mouse slipped to the desktop, so I killed the desktop and got a mostly black screen instead.

From that point, what is the fastest way to get a working desktop back? I assume that would be going to a terminal session and killing or starting the right process(es), but which?

(Running (K)Ubuntu 14.05, so KDE 4.13)

Comment: `kstart plasma-desktop` or `kstart plasmashell` for kde5?

Comment: It says it can't connect to the X server.

Comment: `strg+alt+F1`, restart your xserver?

Comment: well I tried `startx` but still the same problem.